# how to access Taxonomy change log

Tags: 2010, taxonomy

I can see audit log at web application level, but how can I see audit log for modifications in managed metadata application content and schema changes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there is a TaxonomyHiddenList added to the site collection root. You can track changes and updates from there.

So, you can go to audit log and take audit log report for taxonomyhiddenlist to get details of changes.